# Code inside .then after SendGrid request runs on localhost but not on Vercel

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, sendgrid, vercel

I've spent over an hour on this and still can't figure why this console.log won't work on Vercel production. It works fine on localhost but not on Vercel.

```js
async function sendGridMail(email: string, unsubscribeLink: string, msg: string) {
  sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY_TEST!)

  return sgMail.send(msg).then(() => {
    console.log('email sent')
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.message)
  })
}
```

The email is sent just fine, but the console.log simply won't work, no matter what I do.

I've tried including a **return** before the console.log. I've tried removing the **return** from before **sgMail.send**, I've tried including an **await** before **sgMail.send**, but none of this seems to work.
All the above solutions work fine on localhost, though.
This console.log is not important for the function but I would like to understand why it doesn't run on Vercel.

Comment: I don't use Vercel, but does this help? https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/observability/runtime-logs. Make sure you're looking in the right place and you're not filtering out this type of log.

Comment: Also make sure you click the `Show New Logs` button.

Comment: This is just a guess, but are you running this code in a unit test?

Comment: I can see all my logs and I'm able to console.log other things just fine inside the same serverless function, but just that block of code apparently isn't running and I can't understand why.

Comment: You didn't answer my last question though. What I'm trying to determine is if maybe the node process ends before the `console.log` is called, like what can happen when you're doing a unit test. Since `sgMail.send` is asynchronous, it could take maybe 400 ms to execute, by which time the process might have already ended.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't answer because I didn't know what a unit test is. So this is what I'm doing. This code is inside a serverless function called checkUpdates, so i'm accessing it trough: http://example.com/api/checkUpdates which runs the serverless function. But then it doesn't log. I feel like the node process ends before the console logs anything, but I don't get why the process would end without running everything. It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Have you tried awaiting the response to `sendGrid.send` and then returning it after that?